# Magento Site Is Using Apache Error Pages

Tags: php, apache, magento

I have a Magento site. When there is any kind of error (404, 500, 503, etc), it is showing the default apache error page instead of a customizable magento one.

Any ideas of what might be wrong or where to start looking? My understanding is that 404s should be using the CMS -> no route page in the Magento admin, and 500s should be using the 500.phtml pages in the /errors folder in the Magento code base.

Comment: try http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

1) apache mod_rewrite is enabled - here is a php snippet:

```
if (function_exists('apache_get_modules')) {
    $modules = apache_get_modules();
    $mod_rewrite = in_array('mod_rewrite', $modules);
} else {
    $mod_rewrite =  getenv('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE')=='On' ? true : false ;
}
```

Under Debian/Ubuntu, you can enable it using the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

2) under your magento root, check if you have the .htaccess file;

3) under your httpd.conf, check if you have the directive AllowOverride = All for your magento dir

```
<Directory "/var/www/magento">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart your apache after this change.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I checked all these things and they seem to be ok.